# DataTables - set row colour

Tags: datatables

I am using DataTables and would like to set the background colour for each row depending on the input. I followed the directions in the forum:

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36595/change-the-row-color-based-on-column-data

[https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/62460/changing-row-color-at-rendering-time-based-on-column-values]

However, I can not get it to work.

My code is:

```
createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex){
    //console.log('data[3]: ' + data[3]);
    if( data[3] ==  '4'){
        $(row).css("background-color", "red");
    }
},
```

The console.log displays "data[3] is undefined".

I have tried:

```
if( data[3] ===  '4')
```

The full context is:

```
//Show DataTable
    moment.updateLocale(moment.locale(), { invalidDate: "" })
    if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#ymTable' ) ) {
        var ymTable = $('#ymTable').DataTable();
    }
    else {
        var ymTable = $('#ymTable').DataTable( {
            
            createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex){
//              console.log('data[3]: ' + data[3]);
                if( data[3] ==  '4'){
                    $(row).css("background-color", "red");
                }
            },

            info:     false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            order: [[ 3, 'asc' ], [ 1, 'asc' ], [ 2, 'asc' ]],
//          buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
            
            buttons: [
                      {
                          extend: 'copy',
                          exportOptions: {
                              columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          extend: 'csv',
                          exportOptions: {
                              columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          extend: 'excel',
                          exportOptions: {
                              columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          extend: 'pdf',
                          exportOptions: {
                              columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          extend: 'print',
                          exportOptions: {
                              columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
                          }
                      },
                  ],
            columns: [
                  {data: 'cdId',
                      visible: false,
                      searchable: false},
                  {data: 'surname',
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: 'firstname',
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: 'age',
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: 'gender',
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: 'paradePatrol',
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: 'role',
                      defaultContent: ""},
                  {data: null,
                      className: "center",
                      render: function(data,type,row) {
                           if(data.sayId == null || data.sayId == undefined){
                               return ("<input type='checkbox' id=" + data.cdId + " name='update' onchange='ymActivityPatrolFunction(this)' style='zoom: 2.0;'>")
                           }else{
                               return ("<input type='checkbox' id=" + data.cdId + " name='update' onchange='ymActivityPatrolFunction(" + data.cdId + ", " + this.checked + ")' style='zoom: 2.0;' checked>");
                           }
                         },
                  },

                 ],
                 columnDefs: [
                     {targets: 7, orderable: false},
                 ],
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to be, to replace:

```
data[3] ==  '4'
```

with:

```
data.age ==  '4'
```

As in:

```
createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex){
    if( data.age ==  '4'){
        $(row).css("background-color", "red");
    }
},
```